# AngularJS filter already selected option from dynamic field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a form where you can add x number of fields. Each field contains option select. I want to filter out the already chosen option when this option is already chosen in one or multiples field before. Each field has a remove button and the form has 1 add button.

How can I filter out the dynamic fields?
Any help,guidance is most welcome.Thanks in advance. :)

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
          <select data-ng-model="choice.option"
                  data-ng-options="item as item.Value for item in options">
          </select>
          <button data-ng-click="removeChoice(choice)">Remove choice</button>
        <div>
           <button data-ng-show="choices.length <= 4" data-ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add Choice</button>
         </div>
</div>
```

---

And my controller:

```
        $scope.options = [
            {
                "Key": "0",
                "Value": "Select an option"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Option1",
                "Value": "Option1"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Option2",
                "Value": "Option2"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Option3",
                "Value": "Option3"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Option4",
                "Value": "Option4"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Option5",
                "Value": "Option5"
            }
        ];


        $scope.choices = [{ id: '1' }];

            $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
                var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
                    $scope.choices.push({ id: newItemNo, option: $scope.option, value: $scope.value });
            };

            $scope.removeChoice = function () {
                var index = $scope.choices.indexOf(choice);
                $scope.choices.splice(index, 1);
            };
```

---

Comment: You mean for a new `choice` you should have unique `options` which have not selected in other choices? And what is `$scope.option` (no **s**)? Is that just a typo?

Comment: Exactly, the choice you've made shouldn't be available in the next options. It should be filtered out. What do you mean by (no s)?. I push $scope.option, $scope.value and ID to add a new choice.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit busy. I've composed a solution for this, can you please create a simple plunkr so that I can put the stuff on there.

Comment: Hi, ive created a plunker for this http://plnkr.co/edit/sZ7Z4unQKGPHVFuBMBKO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @Wanwan, I've added answer and plunkr for this.

Answer (score 0):

ok
  i can give simple recommendation which will be this.

1: add  variable  $scope.selectedOptions = []; 
  this will  contain list of  already selected  options  from all select elements .

2: create function  $scope.AddSelectedOption(item); 
  this will add the selected  object when  we  change option from any select element because we are going to use for all selects  ng-change= "AddSelectedOption(item);"

3: add checkIfSelected(item);  this will check if given object value is already selected or not ..

will user in   
hope you understand  what it will do  just  check  like this

> $scope.checkIfSelected =  function (item) {
>
> $scope.selectedFound  = $scope.selectedOptions.filter(function
>   (option) {
>                       if(option.value == item.value)
>                       {
>                           return day;
>                       }
>                   });
>                    if($scope.selectedFound.length == 0 )  {   return false; } else {
>       return true;  }
>
> }

This will return true if  give  item found in the options. 
if not out.. you can invite me to help again .

Comment: How can i filter out the option which already been chosen this way? Cause if I filter this out from $scope.option, the option chosen wil also disappear. I now have the selectedOptions which wil be updated on change. But i dont know how to filter this options out.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I'm explaining a basic version of this requirement. See the working example here http://plnkr.co/edit/S9yZpjhY55lXsuifnUAc?p=preview

What wer are doing is maintaining another `options` which is the copy of the original `options`. Copying the `options` will make it to not reference existing options since objects are pass by reference in Javascript.

The main logic is in this function, which modify the `options` on selection:

```
$scope.optionSelected = function(choice) {
    $scope.availableOptions = $scope.availableOptions || angular.copy($scope.options);

    if (choice.option) {
        var index = -1;
        // See if available options has that key
        angular.forEach($scope.availableOptions, function(item, i) {
            if (item.Key === choice.option.Key) {
                index = i;
            }
        });

        if (index > -1) {
            // And then remove it
            $scope.availableOptions.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thnx for answering, this works when you select from top to bottom. When you select the first option, then the second, and you want to change the first again, all options are still available.

Comment: Okay, this can be altered further. Like I said I've given you a basic example which works in a simple way. So, now on change of any select option, you can literray iterate over all choices and remove the selected `availableOptions`. I knew this problem but left for you :-)